# Spring AMQP - How to convert body of message to my custom type?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-amqp

I have a Spring Boot project (let's call it as project A) which uses JMS template to send and receive messages over rabbitmq and works very well. I am not able to change anything on this project.
On other project (let's call it as project B), I want to use Spring AMQP in this project because this is new project but when the project A sends message, project B takes body part of Message as byte array. I defined a RabbitListener to listen queue which will be populated by project A like below:

```
@RabbitListener( queues = "theQueueName")
public void listen(org.springframework.amqp.core.Message incomingMessage) {
    System.out.println("Message read from myQueue : " + new String(incomingMessage.getBody()));
}
```

The body part of incoming message is byte but I need to convert it to custom type which is being used in project A.

What should I do to take this body part as I want?

Answer (score 0):

The ability to inject Spring’s message abstraction is particularly useful to benefit from all the information stored in the transport-specific message without relying on the transport-specific API. The following example shows how to do so:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "myQueue")
    public void processOrder(org.springframework.messaging.Message<Order> order) { ...
}
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#async-annotation-driven-enable-signature